# HTML button only redirect when clicking the text inside

Tags: html

Was wondering why when I clicked my button in HTML it wasn't responding later found out that it will only respond and redirect when I clicked the wording inside "Get Started" was wondering why. This is the code I'm using

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__container">
    <div class="main__content">
      <h1>RAID 2 EARN</h1>
      <h2>TECHNOLOGY</h2>
      <p>We make it easy!</p>
      <button class="main__btn"><a href="raid2earn.html">Get Started</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="imgmain">
      <img id="main__img" src="/IMGS/picture1.svg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why would you expect a button to work if you click somewhere other than the button?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you're actually clicking the anchor tag inside of the button and the button click doesn't have any actions associated with it. The size of the hyperlink is always only the size of its content. You should change your CSS to style your hyperlink to look like a button. Typically, you can do something like this:

```
<a class="main__btn" href="raid2earn.html">Get Started</a>
```

This way you're HTML spec compliant and your hyperlink is styled to look like a button but you're using default browser patterns to complete your action.

Comment: This answer is really good. I found a lot of other hacks to do this, but this is by far the simplest.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you are putting a link tag inside a button because you want a button look and feel. just style your a element the way you want your button to look like as suggested above.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Your anchor tag is enclosing only the 'Get Started' text instead of the button. This way, only the text becomes a link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Actually, every html element has a job.

`<a>` for connecting to outer files

`<button>` for the inside actions

And you can style everyone as you want.

---

**But:**

if you still need to use the `button` and put the `a` inside and need to be able to click the `button` and do the action of the `a`, there are many many ways, some in html, some in css, and others in javascript.

In html, the easiest solution to your issue is to flip the elements, and make the `a` outside the `button` like that:

```
<a href="#">
    <button>Click the button now</button>
</a>
```

This one is just the easiest.

And there are many others in html and css and javascript.

But again, you must use every element in its own purpose.